# Error: act(...) is not supported in production builds of React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, esbuild

I have a specific case here where in my React Redux app I am pulling in libraries from React Testing Library and rendering the import statements of those libraries into a code editor as initial state:

```
import produce from "immer";
import { ActionType } from "../action-types";
import { Action } from "../actions";
import { Cell } from "../cell";

interface CellsState {
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
  order: string[];
  data: {
    [key: string]: Cell;
  };
}

const initialState: CellsState = {
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  order: [],
  data: {},
};

const initialCodeSnippets = [
  `import React, { useState } from 'react';
  import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
  import user from '@testing-library/user-event';
  
  const Counter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return <button onClick={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}>Count: {count}</button>
  };
  render(<Counter />);`,
  `console.log(a);`,
  // Add more initial snippets as needed
];

const reducer = produce((state: CellsState = initialState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.UPDATE_CELL:
      const { id, content } = action.payload;

      state.data[id].content = content;
      return state;
    case ActionType.DELETE_CELL:
      delete state.data[action.payload];
      state.order = state.order.filter((id) => id !== action.payload);

      return state;
    case ActionType.MOVE_CELL:
      const { direction } = action.payload;
      const index = state.order.findIndex((id) => id === action.payload.id);
      const targetIndex = direction === "up" ? index - 1 : index + 1;

      if (targetIndex < 0 || targetIndex > state.order.length - 1) {
        return state;
      }

      state.order[index] = state.order[targetIndex];
      state.order[targetIndex] = action.payload.id;

      return state;
    case ActionType.INSERT_CELL_AFTER:
      const cell: Cell = {
        content: initialCodeSnippets[action.payload.orderIndex],
        type: action.payload.type,
        id: randomId(),
        orderIndex: action.payload.orderIndex,
      };

      state.data[cell.id] = cell;

      const foundIndex = state.order.findIndex(
        (id) => id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (foundIndex < 0) {
        state.order.unshift(cell.id);
      } else {
        state.order.splice(foundIndex + 1, 0, cell.id);
      }

      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}, initialState);

const randomId = () => {
  return Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 5);
};

export default reducer;
```

However, when I do so, in the preview window I get a runtime error saying that:

> Error: act(...) is not supported in production builds of React

I am not sure how to resolve this, since RTL is not a dependency in the application itself but actually being pulled in. ESBuild is not figuring out what path to look at to find RTL or any other library, I am doing it for ESBuild because the bundler needs it.

I take the URL and provide it directly to ESBuild to try to find the source code for a particular library.

Do I need to define `define` differently in the ESBuild plugin?

```
let service: esbuild.Service;
const bundle = async (rawCode: string) => {
  if (!service) {
    service = await esbuild.startService({
      worker: true,
      wasmURL: "https://unpkg.com/esbuild-wasm@0.8.27/esbuild.wasm",
    });
  }

  try {
    const result = await service.build({
      entryPoints: ["index.js"],
      bundle: true,
      write: false,
      plugins: [unpkgPathPlugin(), fetchPlugin(rawCode)],
      define: {
        "process.env.NODE_ENV": '"production"',
        global: "window",
      },
    });

    return {
      code: result.outputFiles[0].text,
      error: "",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      return {
        code: "",
        error: error.message,
      };
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

export default bundle;
```

I tried installing the packages via:

```
npm install @testing-library/jest-dom @testing-library/react @testing-library/user-event --force
```

But I still see that runtime error in the preview window.

So the problem is that under the hood, when I'm calling render, the authors of react-testing-library are wrapping that function in act to make the test run as similar to how it runs in the browser as it can. That's why I am getting this error. Since you're not running that code inside a test environment, act is not supported.

Could I maybe write my own `render()` function and using it instead, but only making it seem like it's using the `render` function from RTL?

Comment: Just a guess. Could it be because `NODE_ENV` is set to production?

Comment: @Anton, when I set it to `development` I no longer got the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either running your [jest tests](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli) with the production build of your application or telling jest to treat it as if it were production with an [environment variable](https://jestjs.io/docs/environment-variables).

Make sure to set `NODE_ENV=test` before running `jest` or set `NODE_ENV=development` all the way.
This issue on Github about a very similar problem might be helpful (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35676).

---

sample `package.json` file:

```
{  
   ...
   "scripts": {
     "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest"
   },
   ...
}
```